# Values over plot– one decimal place, a comma instead of a dot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I make `ggplot` to round values off to one decimal place (`freq` in my code) and a comma instead of a dot? (e.g. 52.13 -> 52,1) Putting a comma instead of a dot should be quite easy by `decimal.mark = ","` or in a more idiomatic way by `label=comma(freq)` (with  `library(scales)`). The thing is that my graph is quite complicated (to me) and I cannot do it on my own.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df <- data.frame(years=c(1991, 1993, 1997, 2001, 2005, 2007, 2011, 2015),
                 freq=c(43.20, 52.13, 47.93, 46.29, 40.57, 53.88, 48.92, 50.92))

p <- (ggplot(df, aes(x=years, y=freq, label=freq)) +
      geom_line(size=.7, color="#999999") + geom_point(size=3, color="black") +
      geom_text(vjust=c(2, -1, -1.5*sign(diff(diff(df$freq))) + 0.5)) +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(panel.border=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
            axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=1.25)) +
      scale_x_continuous("", breaks=seq(1990, 2015, 5), minor_breaks=NULL) +
      scale_y_continuous("", limits=c(0, 60),
                         breaks=seq(0, 60, 10), minor_breaks=NULL))
p
```

Comment: Can't you just round the values beforehand `df$freq <- round(df$freq, digits = 1)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `round` and `point` from `?comma_format`:

```
point <- format_format(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)

p <- (ggplot(df, aes(x=years, y=freq, label=point(round(freq,1)))) +
        geom_line(size=.7, color="#999999") + 
        geom_point(size=3, color="black") +
        geom_text(vjust=c(2, -1, -1.5*sign(diff(diff(df$freq))) + 0.5)) +
        theme_bw() +
        theme(panel.border=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
              axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=1.25)) +
        scale_x_continuous("", breaks=seq(1990, 2015, 5), minor_breaks=NULL) +
        scale_y_continuous("", limits=c(0, 60),
                           breaks=seq(0, 60, 10), minor_breaks=NULL))
```

[image]